# Is there an O(m (log n+ log m))-time algorithm that finds k-th smallest element in a row-wise-sorted two dimensional array?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, sorting, search-algorithms

I prepare for entrance exam and try to practice some hard problems.

The following nice problem is problem 1(c) of [this problem set](https://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/%7Eamitk/semI-2010/csl356/hw3.pdf).

> Suppose we are given a two-dimensional array $A[1...m][1...n]$ in which
> every row $A[i][]$ is sorted, and an integer $k$. Describe an algorithm to find the $k$-th smallest element in $A$ as quickly as possible. How does the running time of your algorithm depend on $m$?

I googled the answer that says that there is one algorithm that can solve this problem in $O(m (\log n+ \log m))$ time. Is it possible? Is there any idea?

I found [an answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/132375/91753) by *Yuval Filmus*. But I couldn't understand it. Is it related or not? It is so hard to understand it as a general algorithm. Since the goal of this site is to provide good material to learn from others, I would like to ask for more general and easier pseudocode or hint that help understand that answer.

Comment: In $O(m (\log n + \log m))$ what? Space? Number of instructions? Multiplications? Comparisons? ...

Comment: @Steven it means there is an algorithm that can be solved this problem in time: O(m (log n + log m)).

Comment: @Steven thanks. time complexity.

Comment: Did you solve $1A$ and $1B$ ?

Comment: There is an easy solution in time $O(m\log n)$ by means of a $n$-way merge with a min-heap, but I guess that better can be achieved.

Comment: I found a solution in Google for (a) and (b), but I think $(C)$ part is very hard. not idea for mentioned time complexity. I mentioned another link in Update part of my question but not idea about steps of that algorithms. @YvesDaoust thanks for your consideration.

Comment: The question you linked contains exactly the answer to your problem.

Comment: @Steven infact I couldn't get the point. I need for simpler or pseudocode version of that answer. I want to learn not more. I read that answer but it's very hard.

Comment: "I need a simpler answer" is not a good fit here.   Instead, I suggest you try to understand that answer, and if you get confused, ask a question about some specific aspect you don't understand.  If you don't understand the answer, then it might be a better choice to practice with easier problems first.

Comment: @D.W. this is not homework that i need other helps. I think there is a good answer is required here. the answer that have clarify simplicity to understand by other easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To find median of $k$ sorted arrays of $n$ elements each in less than $O(nk\log k)$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87695/to-find-median-of-k-sorted-arrays-of-n-elements-each-in-less-than-onk-log)

Comment: @xskxzr if honestly ask me? No, Because There is no algorithm here. I didnt need any answer for my question. I need anyone describe a better understandable algorithm for this problem. maybe the mentioned link is the direct answer, but I asked a question to learn ! at least step-wise algorithm as an answer   !

Answer (score -1):

It is certainly possible in time complexion  O(m + k * log(m)). So it definetly is doable in O(m * (log n + log m)). One way would be to complete the calculation and then wait the appropriate amount of time. I don't know how one would do it in exactly that time without waiting.

From the linked PDF:

> Finally, suppose we are given a two dimensional array A[1 . . . m][1 . . . n] in which
> every row A[i][] is sorted, and an integer k. Describe an algorithm to find the k
> th
> smallest element in A as quickly as possible. How does the running time of your
> algorithm depend on m?

### Update

With the sorted rows we can do this:
First build a heap of the smallest element in each array (storing the index of the array too). Building a heap of size m is O(m).

Then, repeat k times: Take an element from the heap (O (log m)) and insert the next smallest element from the array the element you took was from (O(log m)).

The number taken at iteration k is the k smallest number

Overall, this is O(m + k * log(m)) Of course if k is close to (n*m) this algorithm should be flipped

#### NOTE, this is wrong or at least seems wrong

<del>It is possible to sort a matrix in O(n√nlog√n) [1][1] (External link).</del>

YvesDaoust has rightfully pointed out that sorting n² objects should not be possible in less than O(n² log(n²)) while there are sorting algorithms that are "faster" this is objection is generally correct.

Given that your matrix is already sorted around one axis I am not entirely certain how this will improve performance but thats not even necessary.

To find your solution from that we need O(log n) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303165/10811865) or O(k log k) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966104/10811865) (Both SO links)

Because of Big O rules of summation O(log n) + O(n√nlog√n) = max (O(log n) + O(n√nlog√n)) = O(n√nlog√n) which is even smaller than the result you found.

The problem with Big O notation is, that we are don't know the prefactor or any additional cost, which in this case include the entirety of the searching algorithm (lol)

Comment: maybe you are right. but is there any more sensible algorithm?

Comment: I can't make sense of the article. You can't sort n² elements in less than n² log(n²) comparisons.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean that is not entirely true. Counting sort is O(n+k) with k being the highest number. Tho I did not verify the results of the paper so it might be wrong.

Comment: @SirHawrk: you can sort integers with zero comparisons if you want, but we are not assuming such a frame.

Comment: @YvesDaoust of course you can. I wasn't trying to downplay your objection as should be obvious by my update. Note I first wanted to merge first like you expressed in another comment but that had was only doable in O(n*m) so didn't fit the time constraint