# Proving correctness of a particular algorithm

Tags: algorithms, induction

Suppose there is an array $A[1..n]$.$A$ contains a permutation of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.

We run the following algorithm $m$ times to sort $A$:

- for each odd index of $A$ from left to right ,respectively, put $A[i]$ be the minimum of its and right adjacent (if exists). Also we store index of larger number  for $A[i]$.
- for each even index of $A$ from left to right ,respectively, put $A[i]$ be the minimum of it and right adjacent (if exists).Also we store index of larger number  for $A[i]$.

I guess after $ \lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil $  the algorithm sort number in increasing order. To prove my guess I try to use induction as follow:

For $n=1$ obviously the algorithm works correctly. Suppose it work for $n=k$ now to extend this assumption to $n=k+1$  I found a observation that after at most $ \lceil \frac{k+1}{2}\rceil $ largest and smallest elements will be in their correct place, now how I can conclude that all elements also be in their correct place after $ \lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil $ repeating of the algorithm?

Comment: "I found a observation" is not a sufficient argument. You must justify.

Comment: "Also we augment index of larger number to $A[i]$": no idea what this means.

Comment: The global argument does not seem correct. When you apply the algorithm to $n=k+1$, we don't know where the additional element goes, and that can break the sort of the $k$ first elements and induction is not granted.

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami Could you show how you algorithm works for example on array $[9,6,8,7]$? How does it output the sorted array?

Comment: At the first iteration we have $[6,7,9,8]$ and array with be sort.

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami I am afraid I could not understand your explanation. For $[9,6,8,7]$, could you list the array whenever your algorithm changes it? (I am afraid I could not understand your algorithm at all so far.)